# Gstreamer 0.10.21 - how to update faad decoder version from 0.10.22.3 to 0.10.23

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, vlc, gstreamer, encoding

How to only update one decoder? I have one hardware which is using echo cancel + noise reduction, when i use decoder faad version 0.10.22.3 it does not work even using WebRTC or PJ echo.

I need to debug many things but cant update the faad decoder from 0.10.22.3 to 0.10.23. Any idea how to update it from using apt-get only the faad or all gst-plugin-bad?

```
# gst-launch-0.10 --version
gst-launch-0.10 version 0.10.36
GStreamer 0.10.36
https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10
```

Existing version which is unstable:

```
# gst-inspect-0.10 faad | grep Version
  Version:      0.10.22.3
```

Best/Stable version to install:

```
# gst-inspect-0.10 faad | grep Version
  Version:      0.10.23
```

Answer (score 1):

To get any Ubuntu specific Gstreamer plugin find it here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/

1) before building from source have the dev libraries

```
sudo apt-get install faad libfaad-dev libfaac-dev
```

2) remove existing old faad

```
dpkg --list | grep gstreamer
sudo apt-get remove gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
```

3) install the new one

```
wget http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-bad/gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23.tar.gz
tar xvfz gst-plugins-bad-0.10.23.tar.gz
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-package-name="GStreamer Bad" --with-package-origin="http://www.ubuntu.org/" --enable-gtk-doc --disable-static;
make
sudo make install
```